# fbs freeze failed with Python 3.6.4

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, exe, freeze, fbs

I have the following problem with fbs and Python: I tried to compile Python code and wanted to create an executable .exe file in windows. The command fbs run works fine, but fbs freeze fails.

Package versions:

Python 3.6.4
PyInstaller: 3.4
PyQt5: 5.9.2

Packages that I import:

```
import re
from itertools import chain

import os
import pandas
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from fbs_runtime.application_context.PyQt5 import ApplicationContext
```

The output of fbs freeze --debug you see in the attached image:

[image]

Comment: I am face the same issue. Did you get the solution?

Comment: Please check your pyinstaller version , pyinstaller version 3.5 is working properly. If your version is above 3.5 then degrade to 3.5 (pip install pyinstaller==3.5) it works properly

Answer (score 0):

I used the pyinstaller command to create the exe. This was possible without fbs. Just pyinstaller with the standard comments pyinstaller "...." --onefile --noconsole.
It worked with Python 3.6.4 and pyinstaller 3.4. Perhaps 3.5 would also work. But I know at least that Python 3.8.0 with the newest pyinstaller (even development version from git) doesn't work. I used PyQt5, but some older version 5.12....

It's a bit intransparent...

Best regards,
Markus

Comment: As per the [fbs manual](https://build-system.fman.io/manual/), Python > 3.6 is not supported. We ran into the same issue but downgrading fixed a lot of our problems.

Answer (score 0):

`fbs` runs perfectly fine with python 3.6.x (I am using 3.6.8, PyQt 5.9.2, PyInstaller 3.4).

The python compiler can sometimes get confused if another error happens earlier in the stack. Generally if `fbs freeze` errors when `fbs run` works, that points to a library-include error.

See my answer here to include necessary python library resources in your `./src/freeze/windows/` directory and try freezing again: [The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510900/the-google-api-python-client-distribution-was-not-found-and-is-required-by-the/61531259#61531259)