# (Auto Py To Exe & Python) The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: python

So I wanted to use Auto Py To Exe and got the error:

```py
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application.
```

I tried to downgrade google-api-python-client to 1.8.0 because I saw that on Github at a PyInstaller Error (It didn't work). I also tried to add the google-api-python-client Folder and tried to add it to the hidden imports (Nothing worked). I don't really know what to do, could someone help me?
Thanks.

Edit: So I got it working with just using: easy_install google-api-python-client, after that everything worked perfect.

Comment: I think this solution can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61531259/7787430

Comment: No, but thanks, and I already made an edit that said how I got it working