# The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found on running EXE compiled by pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

My application using google calendar API  with the Google Python client library

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```

for

```
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                        maxResults=100, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
```

Create EXE using py installer

Versions -

```
72 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.1.dev0
72 INFO: Python: 3.9.0
74 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
79 INFO: wrote C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\main.spec
82 INFO: UPX is not available.
83 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 68, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "googleapiclient\http.py", line 67, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "googleapiclient\model.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 480, in get_distribution
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 356, in get_provider
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 899, in require
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 785, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[15548] Failed to execute script main
```

line 10 -

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
```

The application working in pycharm and as python script in CMD
I used py installer in CMD

```
PyInstaller -F       C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\.....
```

in script pycharm

```
import PyInstaller.__main__
PyInstaller.__main__.run([
    'main.py',
    '--onefile',
    '--windowed'
])
```

Im following questions about this but did not find the answer
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510900/the-google-api-python-client-distribution-was-not-found-and-is-required-by-the)

Comment: @DaImTo I did it . Im using google_api_python_client 1.12.5 and moved it to recommended folders

Answer (score 0):

The solution

1. copy the folder-- google_api_core-1.23.0-py3.8.egg-info-- to execute directory
2. rename folder name to ---google_api_python_client.egg-info--

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, Copy Google directories from your Python Application install locations `Python//Lib/site-packages` directory to the `dist/<dot_py_file>` directory created by pyinstaller.